# SIU Toba - Apache: No inicia el servidor Apache

Tags: apache, ubuntu

Hola, instalé SIU Toba (versión 2.7.11) en Ubuntu 16.04, siguiendo la guía de instalación de la página oficial (https://toba.siu.edu.ar/trac/toba/wiki/Instalacion/Linux). Instalé los siguientes paquetes: `libapache2-mod-php libapache2-mod-php7.0 php-cli php-common php-curl php-gd php-pgsql php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-curl php7.0-gd php7.0-json php7.0-opcache php7.0-pgsql php7.0-readline apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils subversion graphviz`

Al ejecutar el archivo "instalación", luego de terminar de instalar te pide que hagas tres pasos de configuración, el primero es linkear dos archivos de configuración, el segundo es que reinicies el servidor Apache y pruebes entrar al localhost, y acá es donde aparece el problema:

Ingreso como root (`sudo su`), y luego ejecuto `service apache2 restart` y la salida es la siguiente: `Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`
Aparte, que no puedo ingresar al localhost ni al toba_editor.

Al ejecutar `systemctl status apache2.service` me sale lo siguiente:

```
apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since vie 2017-10-13 11:34:47 ART; 2min 40s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 10457 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

oct 13 11:34:47 Gustavo-PC apache2[10457]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
oct 13 11:34:47 Gustavo-PC apache2[10457]: Output of config test was:
oct 13 11:34:47 Gustavo-PC apache2[10457]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 49 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/toba_2_7.conf:
oct 13 11:34:47 Gustavo-PC apache2[10457]: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server config
oct 13 11:34:47 Gustavo-PC apache2[10457]: Action 'configtest' failed.
oct 13 11:34:47 Gustavo-PC apache2[10457]: The Apache error log may have more information.
oct 13 11:34:47 Gustavo-PC systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
oct 13 11:34:47 Gustavo-PC systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
oct 13 11:34:47 Gustavo-PC systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
oct 13 11:34:47 Gustavo-PC systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Y al ejecutar `journalctl -xe` me tira:

```
oct 13 11:32:15 Gustavo-PC snap-repair[10399]: error: cannot use snap-repair on a classic system
oct 13 11:32:15 Gustavo-PC systemd[1]: Started Automatically fetch and run repair assertions.
-- Subject: Unit snap-repair.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit snap-repair.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
oct 13 11:32:20 Gustavo-PC org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer[1797]: ** (zeitgeist-fts:2724): WARNING **: Unable to get info on application://nautilus-a
oct 13 11:34:37 Gustavo-PC sudo[10439]:  gustavo : TTY=pts/6 ; PWD=/home/gustavo ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/su
oct 13 11:34:37 Gustavo-PC sudo[10439]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
oct 13 11:34:37 Gustavo-PC su[10440]: Successful su for root by root
oct 13 11:34:37 Gustavo-PC su[10440]: + /dev/pts/6 root:root
oct 13 11:34:37 Gustavo-PC su[10440]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
oct 13 11:34:37 Gustavo-PC su[10440]: pam_systemd(su:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session
oct 13 11:34:47 Gustavo-PC systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Apache2 web server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has finished shutting down.
oct 13 11:34:47 Gustavo-PC systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has begun starting up.
oct 13 11:34:47 Gustavo-PC apache2[10457]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
oct 13 11:34:47 Gustavo-PC apache2[10457]:  *
oct 13 11:34:47 Gustavo-PC apache2[10457]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
oct 13 11:34:47 Gustavo-PC apache2[10457]: Output of config test was:
oct 13 11:34:47 Gustavo-PC apache2[10457]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 49 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/toba_2_7.conf:
oct 13 11:34:47 Gustavo-PC apache2[10457]: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server config
oct 13 11:34:47 Gustavo-PC apache2[10457]: Action 'configtest' failed.
oct 13 11:34:47 Gustavo-PC apache2[10457]: The Apache error log may have more information.
oct 13 11:34:47 Gustavo-PC systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
oct 13 11:34:47 Gustavo-PC systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
oct 13 11:34:47 Gustavo-PC systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
oct 13 11:34:47 Gustavo-PC systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
oct 13 11:35:01 Gustavo-PC CRON[10473]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
oct 13 11:35:01 Gustavo-PC CRON[10474]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
oct 13 11:35:01 Gustavo-PC CRON[10473]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Al parecer es un error en el archivo de configuración de Toba, en la linea 49.

**Archivo toba_2_7.conf**:

```
Alias /gustavo "/home/gustavo/toba_2.7.11/www"
    <Directory "/home/gustavo/toba_2.7.11/www/">
        SetEnv TOBA_DIR     "/home/gustavo/toba_2.7.11"
            Options MultiViews FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
            Require all granted
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>


#Configuracion del SP de SAML
Alias /gustavo_sp "/home/gustavo/toba_2.7.11/php/3ros/simplesamlphp/www"
<Directory /home/gustavo/toba_2.7.11/php/3ros/simplesamlphp/www>
    SetEnv TOBA_INSTALACION_DIR "/home/gustavo/toba_2.7.11/instalacion"
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all granted
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

#Proyecto: toba_editor
Alias /toba_editor/2.7 "/home/gustavo/toba_2.7.11/proyectos/toba_editor/www"
<Directory "/home/gustavo/toba_2.7.11/proyectos/toba_editor/www/">
    SetEnv TOBA_DIR         "/home/gustavo/toba_2.7.11"
    SetEnv TOBA_PROYECTO    "toba_editor"
    SetEnv TOBA_INSTALACION_DIR "/home/gustavo/toba_2.7.11/instalacion"
    SetEnv TOBA_INSTANCIA   "produccion"
    DirectoryIndex aplicacion.php

    AllowOverride None
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all granted
    </IfModule>

    #API REST
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /toba_editor/2.7
    Options FollowSymLinks SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteRule ^rest/(.*)$ rest.php/$1 [PT,L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^rest$      rest.php/   [PT,L,QSA]
    SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
</Directory>

#Proyecto: toba_referencia
Alias /toba_referencia/2.7 "/home/gustavo/toba_2.7.11/proyectos/toba_referencia/www"
<Directory "/home/gustavo/toba_2.7.11/proyectos/toba_referencia/www/">
    SetEnv TOBA_DIR         "/home/gustavo/toba_2.7.11"
    SetEnv TOBA_PROYECTO    "toba_referencia"
    SetEnv TOBA_INSTALACION_DIR "/home/gustavo/toba_2.7.11/instalacion"
    SetEnv TOBA_INSTANCIA   "produccion"
    DirectoryIndex aplicacion.php

    AllowOverride None
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all granted
    </IfModule>

    #API REST
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /toba_referencia/2.7
    Options FollowSymLinks SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteRule ^rest/(.*)$ rest.php/$1 [PT,L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^rest$      rest.php/   [PT,L,QSA]
    SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
</Directory>

#Proyecto: toba_usuarios
Alias /toba_usuarios/2.7 "/home/gustavo/toba_2.7.11/proyectos/toba_usuarios/www"
<Directory "/home/gustavo/toba_2.7.11/proyectos/toba_usuarios/www/">
    SetEnv TOBA_DIR         "/home/gustavo/toba_2.7.11"
    SetEnv TOBA_PROYECTO    "toba_usuarios"
    SetEnv TOBA_INSTALACION_DIR "/home/gustavo/toba_2.7.11/instalacion"
    SetEnv TOBA_INSTANCIA   "produccion"
    DirectoryIndex aplicacion.php

    AllowOverride None
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all granted
    </IfModule>

    #API REST
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /toba_usuarios/2.7
    Options FollowSymLinks SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteRule ^rest/(.*)$ rest.php/$1 [PT,L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^rest$      rest.php/   [PT,L,QSA]
    SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
</Directory>
```

**Archivo apache2.conf**:

```
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf-enabled
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   `-- sites-enabled
#       `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según dice el error:

> Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a
>   module not included in the server config

Que traducido sería:

> Comando 'RewriteEngine' inválido, quizás mal escrito o definido por un
>   modulo no incluido en la configuración.

O sea, te falta el módulo `RewriteEngine`.

Por acá anda la respuesta de cómo instalarlo: [StackOverflow: .htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144634/htaccess-invalid-command-rewriteengine-perhaps-misspelled-or-defined-by-a-m#comment20374533_10144634):

`ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load`

O bien:

`a2enmod rewrite`